# Linux cut, paste

Tags: linux, awk, sed, paste, cut

I have to write a script file to cut the following column and paste it the end of the same row in a new .arff file. I guess the file type doesn't matter.

**Current file:**

```
63,male,typ_angina,145,233,t,left_vent_hyper,150,no,2.3,down,0,fixed_defect,'<50'
67,male,asympt,160,286,f,left_vent_hyper,108,yes,1.5,flat,3,normal,'>50_1'
```

**The output should be:**

```
male,typ_angina,145,233,t,left_vent_hyper,150,no,2.3,down,0,fixed_defect,'<50',63
male,asympt,160,286,f,left_vent_hyper,108,yes,1.5,flat,3,normal,'>50_1',67
```

how can I do this? using a Linux script file?

Comment: It's not called "cut" and "paste" when talking about scripting. It's called moving data around, or "transposing". Stack Overflow is also the place to come when you've written code but it isn't working, it isn't a service to write code for you. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: `awk` and `sed` can do the job, but that's not to say they're the best tool for the job. Consider using something more friendly and forgiving, like Python, Ruby, Perl, or even Node.js, all of which come with most Linux distributions.

Comment: I already able to swap columns using awk 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} {print $2,$5,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$1}' try.txt > try1.txt  however the results have some issuse, like everything get printed in same line. Any way thank you

Comment: @PradeepPallegama, please edit your post your edits into your post only. Also try my solution and let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^([^,]*),(.*)$/\2,\1/' Input_file
```

Brief explanation,

- `^([^,]*)` would match the first field which separated by commas, and `\1` behind refer to the match
- `(.*)$` would be the remainding part except the first comma, and `\2` would refer to the match

Comment: Now i need the result without the comma. what should i change from :sed -e"s/^\([^,]*\),\(.*\)/\2 \1/g " > temp1.txt  code?

Comment: Found the solution. used  tr "," " " it works whole script works without altering any data set, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Shorter **awk** solution:

```
$ awk -F, '{$(NF+1)=$1;sub($1",","")}1' OFS=, input.txt
```

gives:

```
male,typ_angina,145,233,t,left_vent_hyper,150,no,2.3,down,0,fixed_defect,'<50',63
male,asympt,160,286,f,left_vent_hyper,108,yes,1.5,flat,3,normal,'>50_1',67
```

Explanation:

```
{$(NF+1)=$1        # add extra field with value of field $1
 sub($1",","")     # search for string "$1," in $0, replace it with ""
}1                 # print $0
```

EDIT: Reading your comments following your question, looks like your swapping more columns than just the first to the end of the line. You might consider using a swap function that you call multiple times:

```
func swap(i,j){s=$i; $i=$j; $j=s}
```

However, this won't work whenever you want to move a column to the end of the line. So let's change that function:

```
func swap(i,j){
    s=$i
    if (j>NF){
        for (k=i;k<NF;k++) $k=$(k+1)
        $NF=s
    } else {
        $i=$j
        $j=s
    }
}
```

So now you can do this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
{swap(1,NF+1); swap(2,5)}1
func swap(i,j){
    s=$i
    if (j>NF){
        for (k=i;k<NF;k++) $k=$(k+1)
        $NF=s
    } else {
        $i=$j
        $j=s
    }
}
```

and:

```
 $ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
male,t,145,233,typ_angina,left_vent_hyper,150,no,2.3,down,0,fixed_defect,'<50',63
male,f,160,286,asympt,left_vent_hyper,108,yes,1.5,flat,3,normal,'>50_1',67
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using sed or awk, the shell can handle this easily

```
while read l;do echo ${l#*,},${l%%,*};done <infile
```

If it's a win file with \r

```
while read l;do f=${l%[[:cntrl:]]};echo ${f#*,},${l%%,*};done <infile
```

If you want to keep the file in place.

```
printf "%s" "$(while read l;do f=${l%[[:cntrl:]]};printf "%s\n" "${f#*,},${l%%,*}";done <infile)">infile
```